# why use bridge mode in docker-compose can't access jenkins by browser in Windows

Tags: networking, docker-compose, dock

In virtual machine ，firewall is closed ，I want use docker-compose to install Jenkins and  set network mode into bridge and set port mapping，docker is success to enabled  ，and we can use IP of  virtual machine and port of mapping to access by curl command

but i can't access jenkins by browser in windows，so i try to set network mode into host mode ，finally i can access Jenkins by browser in Windows，why use bridge mode in docker-compose can't access jenkins by browser in Windows，Thank you in advance